# circleCI 2.0 does not add the environment variable

Tags: ubuntu, continuous-integration, yaml, circleci, circleci-2.0

I recently switched to circleCI 2.0 from TravisCI and I am facing an issue when I try to: `export PATH="$MINICONDA/bin:$PATH"` ,
it does not add the path variable. 
I tried to debug it using the SSH connection. I first checked if the path variable is set (it was not), later I tried to set it manually and it worked. However, it does not work when the build is performed automatically. 
Here is the error message:

```
 Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: Traceback (most
 recent call last):   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   File
 "/tmp/pip-build-m_klG2/snakemake/setup.py", line 13
     print("At least Python 3.5 is required.\n", file=sys.stderr)
```

It basically, does not see the python (3.6) installed through conda and tries to run the `pip install -r python-requirements.txt` command with the default python (2.7).

 I must be missing something but I could not figure it out.
I provide the complete `config.yml` file below. I would be very appreciated if you could explain this problem.

```
 version: 2
 jobs:
   build:
     branches:
       only:
         -dev
     machine: true
     working_directory: ~/repo
     steps:
       - checkout
       - run:
           name: install miniconda
           command: |
             cd /home/circleci
             export MINICONDA=$HOME/miniconda
             export PATH="$MINICONDA/bin:$PATH"
             hash -r
             wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
             bash miniconda.sh -b -f -p $MINICONDA
             conda config --set always_yes yes
             conda update conda
             conda info -a
             conda create -n testenv python=3.6.0
             source activate testenv
       - run:
           name: install requirements
           command: |
             cd /home/circleci/repo
             pip install -r python-requirements.txt
             pip install pytest-ordering
       - run:
           name: download sample dataset
           command: |
             cd /home/circleci/repo/unit_tests/test_data
             wget http://cf.10xgenomics.com/samples/cell-exp/2.1.0/t_3k/t_3k_filtered_gene_bc_matrices.tar.gz
             tar -xvfz t_3k_filtered_gene_bc_matrices.tar.gz
       - run:
           name: run tests
           command: |
             cd /home/circleci/repo
             pytest ./unit_tests
       - store_artifacts:
           path: test-reports
           destination: test-reports
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I solved it using the Interpolating Environment Variables in [the docs 2.0](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#interpolating-environment-variables).

Steps:

1. Append the environment variable to the ~/.bashrc 
   `echo 'export MINICONDA=$HOME/miniconda' >> ~/.bashrc`
2. source the ~/.bashrc in the rules that you want to access those variables 
   `source ~/.bashrc`

Config file:

```
    version: 2
    jobs:
      build:
        branches:
          only:
            -dev
        machine: true
        working_directory: ~/repo
        steps:
          - checkout
          - run:
              name: install miniconda
              command: |
                cd /home/circleci
                echo 'export MINICONDA=$HOME/miniconda' >> ~/.bashrc
                echo 'export PATH="$MINICONDA/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
                source ~/.bashrc
                hash -r
                wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
                bash miniconda.sh -b -f -p $MINICONDA
                conda config --set always_yes yes
                conda update conda
                conda info -a
                conda create -n testenv python=3.6.0
                echo 'source activate testenv' >> ~/.bashrc
                source ~/.bashrc
          - run:
              name: install requirements
              command: |
                source ~/.bashrc
                cd /home/circleci/repo
                # a requirement has install-time dependency on numpy
                pip install numpy
                pip install -r python-requirements.txt
                pip install pytest-ordering
          - run:
              name: download sample dataset
              command: |
                cd /home/circleci/repo/unit_tests/test_data
                wget http://cf.10xgenomics.com/samples/cell-exp/2.1.0/t_3k/t_3k_filtered_gene_bc_matrices.tar.gz
                tar -zxvf t_3k_filtered_gene_bc_matrices.tar.gz

          - run:
              name: run tests
              command: |
                source ~/.bashrc
                cd /home/circleci/repo
                pytest ./unit_tests
          - store_artifacts:
              path: test-reports
    destination: test-reports


  [1]: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#interpolating-environment-variables
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good use case for the `environment` [flag](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#declaring-an-environment-variable-for-a-step).

```
- run:
    name: install miniconda
    environment:
      MINICONDA: $HOME/miniconda
      PATH: $MINICONDA/bin:$PATH
    command: |
      cd /home/circleci
      hash -r
      wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
      bash miniconda.sh -b -f -p $MINICONDA
      conda config --set always_yes yes
      conda update conda
      conda info -a
      conda create -n testenv python=3.6.0
      source activate testenv
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This I also tried. However in my scenario, I have to share some of those environment variables between certain rules. That's why in the end I decided to use the suggestion at the 'interpolating environment variables' section of the documentation. It seems a bit redundant, but It works for my case. Please let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: If you need it for multiple commands, perhaps a better fit would be defining them for the job or the container? I don't really understand the upside to interpolation for you, but maybe I don't have enough clarity on what your actual need/use case is.

Comment: Right, that should also do it. Interpolation doesn't really have an upside actually. I found it easier since I was going to use the `source ~/.bashrc` command for activating the conda environments anyways.

Comment: but does it really work for you? i end up having circle ci treating it as constant, i.e. it will be set to '$HOME/miniconda' string, but not to '/home/circleci/miniconda'...  see https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#setting-an-environment-variable-in-a-shell-command <-- 

    "While CircleCI does not support interpolation when setting environment 
    variables, it is possible to set variables for the current shell by using 
    BASH_ENV"

Comment: You should not set the PATH variable to a specific path because you may break standard `checkout` steps. CircleCI generally defines PATH.